# When to use @Model and Model In MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Using VS 2013, C#, in my PartialView I have the following;

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyObject
```

I can access the model properties by;

```
@Model.MyProperty
```

Or

```
Model.MyProperty
```

I noticed that if I don't use the @Model, I don't get the IntelliSense to show the object property names.    Apart from that they both work exactly the same.

Therefore when should I use @Model.MyProperty and when should I use just Model.MyProperty?

Comment: The first statement strongly types your view

Comment: The other statements access the view data and you need the @ sign if you want to seperate code from markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '@' sign tells the Razor View Engine that an inline expression follows. But the engine is smart enough that you don't need the '@' sign in some cases. For example in simple code blocks like

```
@{ 
  int x = 123; 
  string y = Model.AStringProperty;
}
```

or if your are using multiple Razor/C# statements after another:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.List.Count(); i++) {
        var image = Model.List[i];

        <div class="item @(i == 0 ? "active" : "")">
        (... other stuff ...)
        </div>
 }
```

What's a little bit strange is that you don't get IntelliSense - you should get one.

Some more examples:
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

So the (runtime)compiler will tell you when to use the '@' sign or not.

Answer (score 0):

The @ at the beginning is marking the following text as a code element, not view markup. So:

```
<li>@Model.Name</li>
```

or

```
<li>
    @if(condition){
        Model.Name
    }
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the should never work both the same.

If you are in a text block, only `@Model.MyProperty` should work. Other text should be displayed. (The @ introduces a "mini code block")
In a code block, `Model.MyProperty` works fine, but the @ should be a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The `@` symbol is used by the Razor parser to indicate C# code and is used to  indicate inline expressions, single statement blocks, and multi-statement block.

It also has the benefit of strong typing your reference to the model.

This is why you're able to create code blocks such as the following:

```
@{ 
  int x = 123; 
  string y = "because.";
}
```

If your reference to the model is wrapped in a code block like `@{}` then you do not need to prefix your model reference with the `@` symbol.

With this in mind I would always try to use the `@` prefix when possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "strong typing"? Can you add an example to "then you do not need to prefix your model reference with the `@` symbol"?