# How to know whether I need @ in Razor Page attributes?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to know the rule when I have to use `@` in Razor page attributes.

For example,

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly">

<input asp-for="Movie.ID" />

<label asp-for="Movie.Title" ></label>

<span asp-validation-for="Movie.Title" >
```

we don't need `@` but

```
<a asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Movie.ID">Edit</a>
```

we do need `@`.

What is the rule?

## Edit

I am only talking about the attributes. Why do some attributes need `@` and other attributes do not need `@`? The attributes are highlighted by gray rectangles.

[image]

In other words,

> Why does `asp-route-id` need `@` while `asp-for` or `asp-validation-summary` don't need `@`?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch. The Microsoft Docs contains many articles about the Razor syntax, including where it's needed the `@` to go from markup to c#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use @Model and Model In MVC 4 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419522/when-to-use-model-and-model-in-mvc-4-razor)

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity No, I understood it, and I work daily with Razor. I've also read the docs I mentioned

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity In that case, `asp-for` already contemplates the `@Model` but `asp-route-id` doesn't (because it could be any value, c# or hard-coded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to look at each `TagHelper` and their properties in order to know exactly.

As a reference:

- Needs `@`: [`public string Action { get; set; }`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/AnchorTagHelper.cs#L64)
- Does not need `@` (bound to `Model`): [`public ModelExpression For { get; set; }`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/InputTagHelper.cs#L90)

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Mmm, no, sorry, I've never needed/changed/looked at the `@namespace` directive. I've only worked with MVC, haven't played with Razor Pages yet. AFAIK, I've always let that be as it's auto-generated

Comment: OK. Thank you very much!

Comment: The given links are broken now. Archived issues maybe.